# Using StrictButton in Django Crispy Forms

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use crispy forms. I'm unsure where `StrictButton` is imported from as below (see code) gives me a error:

**NameError: global name 'StrictButton' is not defined**

How to resolve?

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Fieldset, ButtonHolder, Submit

 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompanyUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
        'email',
        'password',
        'remember_me',
         StrictButton('Register', css_class='btn-default'),
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually importing `StrictButton`. Add it to your import statement and it should work

Comment: I tried: from crispy_forms.layout import StrictButton and it does not exist.

Comment: I'll have to ask: what exactly do you expect `StrictButton` to be? I can't find it in the documentation. Are you using the latest version?

Answer (score 14):

Import the StrictButton element like so...

```
    from crispy_forms.bootstrap import StrictButton
```